# php limit cron 1 process at a time by just creating file and checking if exists

Tags: php

```
 public function getTest() {

        if (file_exists("temp/testFile.txt")) {
            echo 'process  is running';
        }
        else {
            echo 'create file';

            $ourFileName = "temp/testFile.txt";
            $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            fclose($ourFileHandle);

            echo 'running task';

            sleep(10);

            unlink('temp/testFile.txt');

            echo 'file deleted';
        }
    }
```

So as you can see there is sleep of 10 seconds, so in that time I could run another process. But when I try to run another process, it looks like file_exists function does not see that file is created (I check in that directory and I see that it is created) and goes to else part of code.

When I manually create file, and run this function, then file_exists checks correctly.  Why file_exists does not see file when it is automatically created?

**Edit:** 
Works good when using different browser or command line. So kind of solved.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. You are using relative paths. Are you 100% sure that you're always talking about the same file? Are you always running the script with the same credentials? Have you enabled full error reporting?

Comment: actually it works when I tried one process in opera and one in chrome. Not both in chrome like earlier.

Comment: "Are you 100% sure that you're always talking about the same file?" I think its same, because it sees the file on different browsers.
" Are you always running the script with the same credentials?" What do you mean? I dont get the question.

Comment: added   error_reporting(E_ALL); to the begginning of the function - in screen at least there were no errors.

Comment: It looks like that server is waiting till one process end when from same browser. I tried simple function which sleeps 10 s and logs time to the file, running both almost same time. By logs I see that another function time is later 11 seconds.

Comment: Operating systems have users and groups and what a program can do or not do depends on the user that runs it—that's what I call credentials. Whatever, I was misguided by the question title. It seems you have a web page, not a command-line script. Your last comment suggests that you're probably using PHP sessions and keep the session file locked until the script ends.

Comment: I am doing this for use with cron but now testing if it works in browser. Actually I am using it on Laravel framework, so it probably creates session. Does that mean it does not allow 2 processes from same browser at same time?

Comment: If you use file based sessions (the default) and keep the session open for 10 seconds, all other scripts that want to use the same session file wait until the file lock is released. Alternatives (make second script crash or allow that session data can change randomly in the middle of your script) are worse. IMHO, you should close the session before the `sleep()` call. In any case, sessions are HTTP-only: they aren't available in command-line.

Comment: Moved function out of laravel, still same 10 seconds differecne. Maybe it would work ok with command line, like it works ok with different browsers - will test now

Comment: tested from cygwin cmd line - works good :) thanks for trying to help